# What could be the purpose of primary keys on all tables being derived from a single table?

Tags: sql, database

I've really been scratching my head over this and don't know how to ask the question well enough to find an answer on Google or StackOverflow etc.

There is a very old system used at work - I don't have access to the server side so can't view its tables, but I do know its an SQL database and have done enough experimenting with the API to see what adding to each table does, and I'm questioning how it allocates primary keys;

It has a lot of tables, each with a primary key as expected, but the primary key on any/all of its tables seems to be allocated so that there is absolutely no duplication of primary keys anywhere in the system.

e.g.

```
add row to table 1 get pk = 1
add row to table 2 get pk = 2
add row to table 1 again, get pk = 3
add row to table 10 and get pk = 4
```

Is this method some sort of old database technique?

What could be the purpose of doing this?

There are more funny nuances that I won't get into detail of, e.g. a certain range of pk's being allocated for certain tables but I just wanted to see if anyone recognises the main principle here and if there's a point to it, or if it's just bad / weird design

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate [so] question, we can just speculate. It sounds to me like these tables are all used as foreign keys in other tables, and they want them to be unique there. For instance student and teacher tables, and then another table can have foreign keys to either of them.

Comment: The only usefulness I can see for using this method would be to identify *what table* a specific element lived in ..  *why* anyone would want to know that?  Beats me -- Troubleshooting / debugging maybe?

Comment: 1) I'd put money on Gordon's speculation on use of a single sequence object to generate all pk values everywhere. 2) Full disclosure, though, I also have to agree with @Barmar that this isn't really a programming question (don't get me wrong, it's an _interesting_ question, it just isn't a _programming_ question), so I'm voting to close.

Comment: I know, I didn't know where to put it, and even if it gets deleted or downvoted at least I did get some responses that helped me! :D

Comment: @Zak maybe yeah, I was thinking something similar i.e. you could identify the table and therefore type of object you were looking at if you only had its primary key but... in context of using the system, when do you ONLY have an object's pk... that's still not really useful! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key only needs to be unique within a single table.  There is no such thing as a primary key across multiple tables.

This might be useful under some circumstances.  For instance, this would allow all entities to be represented in a single table.  This can be handy for "generic" information, such as adding comments to the entities.

More prosaically, I have seen this in older Oracle databases.  Oracle did not have any automated mechanism for generating ids, so this required using a sequence.  As a matter of convenience, laziness, or design, multiple tables might use the same sequence -- resulting in the behavior that you see.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I suspect the latter part of this answer might be close to the truth - I think when adding to any table it'll use the same routine and check for the next highest number within a range allocated to particular tables (which I think has been a problem at some time when the range was exceeded - I see a mix of int keys and then bigint keys which look like they were added during a system update after years of use)

Comment: Seems that the usefulness element of it definitely wasn't the designer's primary concern though, I think it was just how they allocated a key because maybe it was built on an old system that had no automatic pk allocation

Comment: @jamheadart . . . Bad design because MySQL supports auto-incremented primary keys.  Perhaps that was introduced at some point, and the code predates that.

Comment: @jamheadart Do you know what RDBMS it is? Doing this in MySQL would be tricky, since it doesn't have built-in sequence objects.

Comment: Actually looking at the front-end, I have a feeling the system is being allocated its primary keys by a combo of javascript functions and a quick system check... I don't know if I'll dig in to this any more, it seems that it's definitely not a mega-useful design theory that I just wasn't aware of and more of an old system design flaw!